# Creating visual studio extension adding a menu and a form

Tags: c#, vsix

I am trying to add a menu item into my custom extension for visual studio  but when I attempt to compile it says the guidTopLevelMenuPackageCmdSet does not exist even though I have create a command object.

```
<Menus>
  <Menu guid="CommandSet" id="TopLevelMenu" priority="0x700" type="Menu">
  <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu"
          id="IDG_VS_MM_TOOLSADDINS" />
      <Strings>
          <ButtonText>TestMenu</ButtonText>
          <CommandName>TestMenu</CommandName>
      </Strings>
  </Menu>
</Menus>
 
  <!-- In this section you can define new menu groups. A menu group is a container for
     other menus or buttons (commands); from a visual point of view you can see the
     group as the part of a menu contained between two lines. The parent of a group
     must be a menu. -->
  <Groups>
      <Group guid="CommandSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
          <Parent guid="CommandSet" id="TopLevelMenu"/>
      </Group>
  </Groups>
```

Now I want my extension to be able to launch a form how do I achieve this correctly I tried the tutorial here but it wasn't clear where you get the guide from. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-visual-studio-2019-extension/

I started with the basic template but it didnt add the menu correctly when I was debugging is their something im missing.

```
<!-- In this section you can define new menu groups. A menu group is a container for
         other menus or buttons (commands); from a visual point of view you can see the
         group as the part of a menu contained between two lines. The parent of a group
         must be a menu. -->
      <Menus>
          <Menu guid="CommandSet" id="TopLevelMenu" priority="0x700" type="Menu">
              <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu"
                      id="IDG_VS_MM_TOOLSADDINS" />
              <Strings>
                  <ButtonText>TestMenu</ButtonText>
                  <CommandName>TestMenu</CommandName>
              </Strings>
          </Menu>
      </Menus>
     
      <!-- In this section you can define new menu groups. A menu group is a container for
         other menus or buttons (commands); from a visual point of view you can see the
         group as the part of a menu contained between two lines. The parent of a group
         must be a menu. -->
      <Groups>
          <Group guid="CommandSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
              <Parent guid="CommandSet" id="TopLevelMenu"/>
          </Group>
      </Groups>
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else if you look in the vscx file you will see at the bottom the following. Here you will see guidEfCoreCrudBootStrapPackageCmdSet which matches the guid command set value in the ICommand interface you created in the tutorial.

```
<GuidSymbol name="guidEfCoreCrudBootStrapPackageCmdSet" value="{5017a255-b672-4113-b19a-422a35b0af64}">
  <IDSymbol name="MyMenuGroup" value="0x1020" />
  <IDSymbol name="EfCoreCrudBootStrapCommandId" value="0x0100" />
    <IDSymbol name="MyMenuGroup" value="0x1020" />
    <IDSymbol name="SampleCommandId" value="0x0100" />
    <IDSymbol name="SampleMenu" value="0x1021"/>
</GuidSymbol>

<GuidSymbol name="guidImages" value="{14c1b0d2-fd1c-41b4-88f0-9545d5ecdf31}" >
  <IDSymbol name="bmpPic1" value="1" />
  <IDSymbol name="bmpPic2" value="2" />
  <IDSymbol name="bmpPicSearch" value="3" />
  <IDSymbol name="bmpPicX" value="4" />
  <IDSymbol name="bmpPicArrows" value="5" />
  <IDSymbol name="bmpPicStrikethrough" value="6" />
 
</GuidSymbol>
```